# Adding FacebookSDK.framework into my own Static library

Tags: ios, facebook, frameworks, static-libraries

I am creating a static library which i will be using for more than one projects, which i am developing. I will build the static library as .framework file and will drag and drop to use in other projects. It is working fine. Now i am adding some more functionalities to the framework. I am adding FacebookSDK.framework to the static library for log in purpose, but when i drag the framework to another project and build it, it throws an error.

```
"FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h" file not found.
```

Please help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should change your import statement to

```
#import "FacebookSDK.h"
```

And add FacebookSDK.framework to the project which USES your static library.

If you want to build FacebookSDK.framework INTO your own static library. You should open  FacebookSDK.framework and find all the .h and a file named FacebookSDK, and add these files into your static library project.

Comment: Even if we add all headers inside static library, should we import facebook sdk again into main project?

Comment: Yes. .framework s are only linked at build time. And they cannot be build into the binary file of your static library.

Comment: If you want to keep facebook framework inside your static library. You should open FacebookSDK.framework and find all the .h and a file named FacebookSDK (not the alias file), and add these files into your static library project.

Comment: Ok, adding headers will be enough or should i import facebook sdk again into main project?

Comment: headers AND a binary file named FacebookSDK. If you build these two things into your static library (I mean drag them into your Xcode project). You should not be needing them in your main project.

Comment: Which one is best method? 1) Adding Framework in main project or 2) Adding header files inside static library. Please advice. Thank you,

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20880/discussion-between-paramasivan-samuttiram-and-yuao)

Comment: The 1st. Because if somebody like you also build FacebookSDK into his static library. And you are using his static library. There will be two FacebookSDK in your main project. That's not good, may cause some errors when you build your project. You should treat your static library framework as depending on the FacebookSDK.framework, so you add these two frameworks in your main project. This is more logical.

Comment: Thank you @YuAo, Also, cannot i use XIB inside static library?

Comment: @YuAo you have saved my life! Thank you so much! Have been struggling with this issue for two days!

Comment: @ParamasivanSamuttiram hope you will help in my issue did you open the FacebookSDK.framework and copy .h files to your static library and then you don't have to include the FacebookSDK.framework in working projects?

Comment: Hi @YuAo I'm trying to accomplish something similar to this but I want my Framework to not include Facebook SDK, so I can add it into my main projects. I'm struggling with this. Right now, every time I build my framework and run nm in a Terminal window I see that Facebook SDK's classes are linked there. Is there a tutorial that explains how to do that?