# Can a Objective C Framework/Static Library consist of third party framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, static-libraries

This is just an informational question, I have been examining several ways to make frameworks in iOS.

I made 
**Swift Pure frameworks**:- There I got to know that, you have to include the xcodeproject to the application project to use the .framework included in .xocdeproject. So I thought this is not the secure way to giving code to third party and I also I did not find ways to include the third party frameworks to my own framework.

**Objective Static Libraries:-**
In this type libraries, the system is generated a .a file which is secure and the person gonna use does not know the implementation part however found out that if I want to include a third party framework to this, I will have to ask the end user to include that third party project to end application to compile it which will show the end user what all dependancies I have, which I don't want.

My issue is I wan to make a Framework which will consist of all the third party frameworks however, they would be hidden from end user although the codes from them can still be used by end user as required however, end user should not see them listing in my framework.

Is there a way out?

I have gone through many links and found out that many have this doubt as well

Like

[Adding FacebookSDK.framework into my own Static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802168/adding-facebooksdk-framework-into-my-own-static-library)

In this post, one person is asked to get all header files and the framework file and then add that to static libraries to build to add the framework itself, I tried that too without success.

Comment: If the end user of the framework can use objects of the third party frameworks, how will he compile his code without the .h of those frameworks ?

Comment: @Xvolks right. okay is there any way to include .h files from those third party frameworks to my frameworks/static library?

Comment: What you want to do is not best practice. Imagine you link your framework with FacebookSDK version 1, the user links his application with your framework and  FacebookSDK version 2. The resulting application will have two different versions of each object. At runtime which version used is undefined. This will create random crashes and/or weird behaviors.

Comment: No problem that can be avoidable. Is it possible? if yes, how? Thanks

Comment: If you put the .h of the 3rd party frameworks, the end user will know that you use it. You stated that you do not want to. If you add the .h, why not adding the whole framework? It's really a pain in the @ss for the end user. I use myself such framework that use OpenCV in hidden mode (I don't know the version), my application also use OpenCV (latest version). I have random crashes with this configuration. :(

Comment: @Xvolks does not matter, how to use it. please let me know.I want to use this in hidden mode!!

Comment: Just statically link the frameworks. Your end users will hate you. This is just the wrong way.

Comment: I tried adding the .h files however, they are not under the target membership of the static library and I am unable to check that option?

Answer (score 0):

**Do not do that.**

There is literally no good outcome of what you're trying to do. This is very confusing and couples your library API with a different library's API, forcing the user to stick with your version of the 3rd party lib.

If the user will want to use a newer version of the 3rd party dependency, he won't be able to, because it will result in duplicate symbols.

You can't find any information about such practice on the internet, *because nobody does this*.

If you want to distribute an already compiled library, there's no other way than just compile all 3rd party code with it, without exposing the header files.

There's one very big important thing left: you have to make sure that users of your SDK will not end up with duplicate symbols if they also use the 3rd party library!

[More here...](http://blog.sigmapoint.pl/avoiding-dependency-collisions-in-ios-static-library-managed-by-cocoapods/)

[And here...](http://yourcodesucksexception.blogspot.com/2015/06/clang-compiler-under-hood.html)